# Nomear uma célula

Tags: vba

Boa Noite,

estou fazendo uma regra no vba que vai rodar para todas as linhas da planilha. Por isso criei uma variavel, cells(l,3) = "ID", porém quando chamo essa variavel nas fórmulas está retornando a palavra ID ao invés do valor na célula (L,3).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

## Via VBA

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("E2")
r.Name = "ONomeDaCelula"
```

## Alternativa via Interface do Excel

Abra o context menu da célula que deseja definir um nome. Pode fazer isso clicando o botão direito do mouse:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Defina o nome da caixa de diálogo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para testar, Insira um valor na célula

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione outra célula qualquer e invoque o valor pelo input de fómula rápida. Nesse caso é `=foo`

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso terá o resultado esperado

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]